# rails datatables associations get_raw_records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I read over and over again the documentation about this topic but I cant understand/make it work, I'm using antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails gem for my datatables but I cant make work the sort/search feature of tables that includes associations.

Here the links of documentation about it :

https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/77
https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails#associated-and-nested-models

I tried several ways and this is the one that gives me "better" results (at least shows the data).

First, models.

Order

```
        :id => :integer,
 :school_id => :integer,
      :year => :integer,
 :paymethod => :string,
  :contract => :string,
:created_at => :datetime,
:updated_at => :datetime,
    :number => :integer,
:licitacion => :string
```

---

School

```
        :id => :integer,
    :nombre => :string,
       :rut => :string,
 :direccion => :string,
     :email => :string,
:commune_id => :integer
```

Commune

```
       :id => :integer,
     :name => :string,
:region_id => :integer
```

Region

```
        :id => :integer,
      :name => :string,
```

OrderStatus

```
            :id => :integer,
      :order_id => :integer,
:status_type_id => :integer,
    :comentario => :string,
    :created_at => :datetime,
    :updated_at => :datetime
```

StatusType

```
         :id => :integer,
     :nombre => :string,
:descripcion => :string,
 :created_at => :datetime,
 :updated_at => :datetime
```

orders_datatable

```
 def sortable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    @sortable_columns ||= %w(Order.id School.nombre Commune.name Region.name Order.year Order.paymethod Order.contract StatusType.nombre)
  end

  def searchable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    @searchable_columns ||= %w(Order.id School.nombre Commune.name Region.name Order.year Order.paymethod Order.contract StatusType.nombre)
  end

  private

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
        # comma separated list of the values for each cell of a table row
        # example: record.attribute,
        link_to(record.try(:number), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.school.try(:nombre), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.school.commune.try(:name), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.school.commune.try(:region).try(:name), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.try(:year), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.try(:paymethod), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.try(:contract), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        link_to(record.order_statuses.last.status_type.try(:nombre), order_proccesses_path(record)), 
        edit_and_delete_buttons(record)
        ]
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    # insert query here
    Order.joins(:school).all
  end
```

orders.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#orders-table').dataTable
    processing: true
    serverSide: true
    ajax: $('#orders-table').data('source')
    paginType: 'full_numbers'
    responsive: true
    language:
      url: "/assets/Spanish.json" 
    columns: [
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: true,  searchable: true }
        { sortable: false, searchable: false }
      ]
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response by antillas21 :)

```
# if using .includes
def get_raw_records
  Order.includes(
    :school => { :commune => :region }, :order_statuses => :status_type
  )
  .references(
    :school => { :commune => :region }, :order_statuses => :status_type
  ).distinct
end

# alternatively, you can use .joins
def get_raw_records
  Order.joins(
    :school => { :commune => :region }, :order_statuses => :status_type
  ).distinct
end
```

hope this is useful for anybody else

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be interesting for you - http://ajahongir.github.io/ajax-datatables-rails/